# SharePoint List and/or Calendar Custom Email

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, sharepoint-list, sharepoint-email

I have been tasked to create an email for a SharePoint list as well as a leave Calendar and the way that it was described is that SharePoint generates it ? I cannot find anything related to that, which is why I do not think it is possible.

I would have to create an outlook email and then sync it to said list/calendar, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Microsoft 365, I would recommend creating a group connected Team site in SharePoint Online. All Microsoft 365 groups have a shared calendar which can be displayed via a web part in the Team site, along with a shared email address.

[Learn about Microsoft 365 Groups](https://support.microsoft.com/topic/learn-about-microsoft-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2)

> Groups in Microsoft 365 let you choose a set of people that you wish to collaborate with and easily set up a collection of resources for those people to share. Resources such as a shared Outlook inbox, shared calendar or a document library for collaborating on files.

[Create a team site in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/office/create-a-team-site-in-sharepoint-ef10c1e7-15f3-42a3-98aa-b5972711777d)